# PowerShell WebClient.DownloadFile() stops after a few seconds of download

Tags: powershell

This program should download two files into a directory, yet when I run the program, the first 20KB download but then it stops.

This is my code :

```
$javaURL = "https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/14.0.1+7/664493ef4a6946b186ff29eb326336a2/jdk-14.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe"
$eclipseURL = "https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2020-03/R/eclipse-inst-win64.exe&mirror_id=1099"

$outpathJava = "C:\myPath\file1.exe"
$outpathEclipse = "C:\myPath\file.exe"

$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.DownloadFile($javaURL, $outpathJava)
$webClient.DownloadFile($eclipseURL, $outpathEclipse)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use your browser to navigate to the links you just shared, you will see those links are not the executables.

For Java, if you open as text file file1.exe you will see something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Unauthorized Request</title>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/errors/us/assets/hp-styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/errors/us/assets/master-master.css" />

<body style="margin: 0px" bgcolor=#ffffff>
<div id="banner">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" valign="middle" nowrap><a href="http://www.oracle.com"><img src="/errors/us/assets/oralogo-small.gif" width="154" height="19" hspace="10" vspace="25" border="0" ></a></td>
      <td align="right" valign="top" width="70%" nowrap class="padMid"><div id="bannerMid"> </div></td>

      <td width="30%" align="left" valign="bottom" nowrap></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" valign="bottom" nowrap class="padMid"></td>
      <td width="30%" align="left" valign="bottom" nowrap></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- Header END //-->
<table  BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=0 CELLSPACING=0 WIDTH="100%">
...
```

Similar thing for the eclipse link.

I suggest you maybe to use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) to install soft.

[Eclipse](https://chocolatey.org/packages/eclipse)
[Java](https://chocolatey.org/search?q=java)

Install Chocolatey: https://chocolatey.org/install

then in as powershell (as admin):

```
choco install eclipse
```

Comment: do you have any useful links for me to research how to download with chocolatey?